# sudo apt-get update -qq fails in travis 401 Unauthorized

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to build following image in travis CI. However, I am getting 401 authorized. It was working yesterday but today is working.

```
language: c
sudo: required

before_install:

  - curl -OL http://raw.github.com/craigcitro/r-travis/master/scripts/travis-tool.sh
  - chmod 755 ./travis-tool.sh
  - ./travis-tool.sh bootstrap
install:
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_deps
script: ./travis-tool.sh run_tests

after_failure:
  - ./travis-tool.sh dump_logs

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: change
    on_failure: change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Travis has it posted as an incident
https://www.traviscistatus.com/incidents/77q4ts757mzs

Which points to a temporary fix at
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8607

basically add

```
before_install:
- sudo rm -vf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*riak*
- sudo apt-get update
```